# Scraping data from TripAdvisor using R

Tags: r, xpath, rselenium

I want to create a crawler that will scrape some data from Trip Advisor. Ideally, it will 
**(a)** identify the links to all locations to crawl, 
**(b)** collect links to all attractions in each location and 
**(c)** will collect the destination names, dates and ratings for all reviews. 
I'd like to focus on part (a) for now.

Here is the website I'm starting off with:
http://www.tripadvisor.co.nz/Tourism-g255104-New_Zealand-Vacations.html

There is problem here: the link gives top 10 destinations to begin with, and if you then click on "See more popular destinations" it will expand the list. It appears as though it uses a javascript function to achieve this. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with javascript, but I think the following chunk may give clues about how it works:

```
<div class="morePopularCities" onclick="ta.call('ta.servlet.Tourism.showNextChildPage', event, this)">
<img id='lazyload_2067453571_25' height='27' width='27' src='http://e2.tacdn.com/img2/x.gif'/>
See more popular destinations in New Zealand </div>
```

I've found a few useful webscraping packages for R, such as rvest, RSelenium, XML, RCurl, but of these, only RSelenium appears to be able to resolve this, having said that, I still haven't been able to work it out.

Here is some relevant code:

```
tu = "http://www.tripadvisor.co.nz/Tourism-g255104-New_Zealand-Vacations.html"
RSelenium::startServer()
remDr = RSelenium::remoteDriver(browserName = "internet explorer")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate(tu)
# remDr$executeScript("JS_FUNCTION")
```

The last line should do the trick here, but I'm not sure what function I need to call here.

Once I manage to expand this list, I will be able to obtain the links for each destination the same way I would solve part (b) and I think I've already solved this (for those interested):

```
library(rvest)
tu = "http://www.tripadvisor.co.nz/Tourism-g255104-New_Zealand-Vacations.html"
tu = html_session(tu)
tu %>% html_nodes(xpath='//div[@class="popularCities"]/a') %>% html_attr("href")
 [1] "/Tourism-g255122-Queenstown_Otago_Region_South_Island-Vacations.html"                      
 [2] "/Tourism-g255106-Auckland_North_Island-Vacations.html"                                     
 [3] "/Tourism-g255117-Blenheim_Marlborough_Region_South_Island-Vacations.html"                  
 [4] "/Tourism-g255111-Rotorua_Rotorua_District_Bay_of_Plenty_Region_North_Island-Vacations.html"
 [5] "/Tourism-g255678-Nelson_Nelson_Tasman_Region_South_Island-Vacations.html"                  
 [6] "/Tourism-g255113-Taupo_Taupo_District_Waikato_Region_North_Island-Vacations.html"          
 [7] "/Tourism-g255109-Napier_Hawke_s_Bay_Region_North_Island-Vacations.html"                    
 [8] "/Tourism-g612500-Wanaka_Otago_Region_South_Island-Vacations.html"                          
 [9] "/Tourism-g255679-Russell_Bay_of_Islands_Northland_Region_North_Island-Vacations.html"      
[10] "/Tourism-g255114-Tauranga_Bay_of_Plenty_Region_North_Island-Vacations.html"
```

As for step (c), I've found some useful links that might be helpful for that:
https://github.com/hadley/rvest/blob/master/demo/tripadvisor.R
http://notesofdabbler.github.io/201408_hotelReview/scrapeTripAdvisor.html

If you have any tips on how to expand the list of top destinations or how to go through the other steps in a smarter way, please let me know, I'd be really keen to hear from you.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you can try to send a click event to the `<div class="morePopularCities">`. Something like this :

```
remDr$navigate(tu)
div <- remDr$findElement("class", "morePopularCities")
div$clickElement()
```

To expand all locations, you can possibly repeat the above logic in a while loop. Keep clicking on the `<div>` until no more items available (until the `div` no longer in the page) :

```
divs <- remDr$findElements("class", "morePopularCities")
while(length(divs )>0) {
  for(div in divs ){
    div$clickElement()
  }
  divs <- remDr$findElements("class", "morePopularCities")
}
```

I'm not fluent in `R`, you may find my code example not pretty, feel free to suggest.

Comment: thanks @har07 , that worked perfectly! Strangely, though, sometimes it doesn't do anything. It isn't much of a problem though, as I can just spam that button until it disappears (until I get an error). I've noticed another oddity -- using `remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', '//div[@class="popularCities"]/a')` followed by `webElem$getElementAttribute("text")` for example, I only get the first entry. Once again, it isn't a biggie since I can modify my xpath expression to `'//div[@class="popularCities"]/a[X]'` where X is the number I want, but is there a better  way? Many thanks!

Comment: @de1pher try `remDr$findElements(...)` (notice the trailing "`s`" in `findElements`) to get multiple elements, then use `for` loop to get `text` attribute from each element. You are welcome :)